# Simple finite summation

Tags: summation

A little rusty on finite summation. 
Trying to solve the summation of $i$ for $n$ if $i=9$, and the total summation equals $400$.

I solved $400=\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and got around $28$. How does $9$ factor in?

Comment: Could you be a bit more clear?  Does it start at $i=9$, for example?

Comment: you want to solve the equation $$400=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$?

Comment: yes the summation starts at i=9, i am solving for n. I believe the solution is n=21 by re-writing the summation to sum(i+8)=400

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is for the sum from $1$ to $n$, which is $\frac {n(n+1)}2$ as you say.  If you want to start with $9$ and go up, you need to subtract the terms from $1$ to $8$, so your equation would be $$400=\frac {n(n+1)}2-\frac {8 \cdot 9}2$$  You can come within one at $n=29$, but there is no integer solution.

Comment: ~29 is incorrect. To start at 9, I believe it is appropriate to re-write the expression as (sigma(I=1)8+sigma(I=1)I)=400 which give ~21

Comment: You haven't been clear with the question.  I was reading it as $9+10+11+\ldots +n$ which gives $n=29$ as the closest.  If you meant $(8+1)+(8+2)+\ldots +(8+n)$ this gives $n=21$ as the closest.  These are equivalent but your $n$ is $8$ less than my $n$.  Often the most important part of solving a math problem is stating the question precisely.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Why are they equivalent? When is it appropriate to subtract earlier terms?